# Trying to access ViewModel public properties in another ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, mvvm

I have 2 viewmodels:

1)

```
public class TaskTrayViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase where T : IBlotterRow, new()
{
}
```

2)

```
public class BlotterCriteriaViewModel : ViewModelBase , IDataErrorInfo 
{ 
}
```

I am trying to access `TaskTrayViewModel<T>` public properties in BlotterCriteriaViewModel like this

```
public class BlotterCriteriaViewModel : ViewModelBase , IDataErrorInfo 
{
TaskTrayViewModel<IBlotterRow> _all;
    TaskTrayViewModel<IBlotterRow> All
    {
        get { return _all; }
        set { value = _all; }
    }
}
```

While doing above, the following error is coming : 'DMS.Common.Interfaces.Blotter.IBlotterRow' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'DMS.GUI.ViewModels.TaskTrayViewModel'.

Kindly Suggest? How to rectify it?

Comment: You might want to switch this ;) set { value = _all; } to set { _all = value; }

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `new()` generic constraint, because you can't create an Interface with new, in fact you can't create any interface. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) about constraints. You might want to use `class`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a property defined like that:

```
TaskTrayViewModel<IBlotterRow> _all;
TaskTrayViewModel<IBlotterRow> All
{
    get { return _all; }
    set { value = _all; }
}
```

because you are not specifying a concrete implementation of IBlotterRow. If you have a concrete implementation of the `TaskTrayViewModel<T>` class such as

`public class MyImpl: TaskTrayViewModel<MyClass>`

then you may have that as a property in another class. Otherwise you must define a non-generic base class for `TaskTrayViewModel<T>` containing the properties you need, or make `BlotterCriteriaViewModel` generic and have the property defined with its type parameter:

```
public class BlotterCriteriaViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase , IDataErrorInfo 
{
    TaskTrayViewModel<T> _all;
    TaskTrayViewModel<T> All
    {
       get { return _all; }
       set { value = _all; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, what exactly do you want to do, but the error says (according to your constraints) that to use `TaskTrayViewModel<T>` generic type you need non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor for your type parameter:

`public class MyBlotterRow : IBlotterRow
{
...
}`

Then you can write your property declaration as `TaskTrayViewModel<MyBlotterRow> _all;`